# elementary os natural scrolling disabled when disable while typing is on?

Tags: system, touchpad

i started the syndaemon like this to enable **disable while typing** option `syndaemon -i 1 -d` but after that **natural scrolling** doesn't work, so how do i get both to work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my version of Elementary, I do NOT have the option to disable touchpad while typing... [![Screenshot of my Elementary settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RiZFc.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RiZFc.png)

Comment: i am using freya 0.3.1

Comment: I fear that is not an answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

In the System Settings app there is a section called "Mouse and Touchpad" which contains check boxes for both "Disable while typing" and "Natural Scrolling". Checking both of these options seems to be at least a partial solution as it disables scrolling while typing (the mouse pointer continues to work) and preserves natural scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to disable both mouse pointer and natural scrolling while typing but reenable once i stop typing, i have the disabling part but the scrolling doesn't reenable.